# How to add/include views in Laravel using Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm bit stuck at a place. I've got some views of small `HTML sections` which when combined gives the complete HTML page. I'm trying to build a `website builder` with `Jquery`, where I'm having a `drop event` which adds those particular `views`:

For example I've got `HTML` for `slideshow`:

```
<div id="slideshow" data-nitsid="2">
    <div class="revolution-slider">
        <ul>
            <!-- SLIDE  -->
            @foreach($contents->slider as $sliders)
                <li data-transition="{{ $sliders->transition }}" data-slotamount="{{ $sliders->slotamount }}" data-masterspeed="{{ $sliders->masterspeed }}">
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="{{ URL::asset($sliders->url) }}" alt="">
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my `JQuery` code:

```
nitsbuilder.dropeventhandler = function ($item, $position) {
    var nits_id = $item.data('nitsid');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: dropurl,
        data: { nits_id: nits_id, _token: token},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            nitsbuilder.adder($item, $position, data);
        }
    });

}
```

Before I was having `html codes` in the `database` so it was easier to pull out the html and add to the HTML page, now I'm having `html in views`, how can I `push/include` this `HTML code` or `view` to `ajax request` so that my nitsbuilder.adder function executes placing the view through my controller.

My present `Controller` is:

```
class DropeventController extends Controller
{
    public function htmlcode(Request $request)
    {
        $pluginid = $request['nits_id'];
        $code = Plugins::findOrFail($pluginid);
        $htmlcode = $code->code;
        return response()->json(['htmlcode' => $htmlcode]);
    }

}
```

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Can you remove the stuff that is already working fine from your code? It should be enough to show your actual ajax call, the routes and the controller, maybe add the migration / table structure you are using here

Comment: @FrankProvost Done!

Comment: So currently you store your html snippets in the database? And you would prefer to return blade views?

Comment: @FrankProvost yes!

Comment: I'll write an answer - gimme a sec

Comment: @FrankProvost Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create html strings from blade views using \View::make

e.g. let's assume you have the following folder strucutre

- project

  - ...
  - ressources
  - views

    - snippets
    - snippetA
    - snippetB

You could now create a route / controller accepting a "name" parameter and then do the following

```
$name = "snippetA"; // get this from parameters

$html = \View::make("snippets.$name")->render();
```

You might need to also add variables depending on your views

```
$name = "snippetA"; // get this from parameters
$errors = []; // error variable might be needed

$html = \View::make("snippets.$name", compact('errors'))->render();
```

You can then return this html string

```
return ['html' => $html];
```

And access it from your ajax done function.

I hope this helps

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your html is in view file called abc.blade.php, you can return the rendered view from your controller in json.

```
return response()->json([
'htmlcode' => View::make('abc')->render();
]);
```